# Possible to substitute mixins used inside other mixins?

Tags: less

I have some Less mixins I use to create a site navigation, which is mostly the same in every project.

I've made it editable through global variables, but these get long and ungainly for nested elements. For example:

```
@nav-main-sub-menu-item-title-text-transform: uppercase;
```

It would be really nice if I could disable a specific nested mixin, and re-instantiate it manually.

```
// Main nav

.Nav() {

  .nav {

    display:block;

    & when (@Nav-Item = default) {
      .Nav-Item();
    }

    // Would be nice to insert a custom .Nav-Item() here
    // when @Nav-Item is set to 'custom'

  }

}

.Nav();

// Enables Nav-Item

@Nav-Item: default;

// Nav item

.Nav-Item(@color: red) {

  .item {

    color: @color;

  }

}

// Override 

@Nav-Item: custom;

.Nav-Item(@color: blue);
```

I could add '.nav' into the item mixin itself to make it more self-encapsulated, but this goes against the "don't repeat yourself" mantra...

Plus, media queries, etc, make things more complicated than just this simple example.

```
.Nav-Item(@color: red) {

  .nav {

    .item {

      color: @color;

    }

  }

}
```

I don't know if there's a good solution, but I just figured I'd put this out there.

Comment: There're multiple methods - it's hard to suggest anything specific though w/o knowing every detail of your exact goal. Discover [`default()` guard](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-default), [arg-pattern-matching](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-pattern-matching), [DRs](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) etc. (Besides, think if you actually need that indirect control via `@Nav-Item`, i.e. can't you control things *directly* via custiomizing the mixins definitions - for example via same arg-pattern-matching or other ways).

Comment: [Example](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%2F%2F%20usage%3A%5Cn%5Cnfoo%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct.nav-item()%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20default%3A%5Cn%5Cn.nav-item()%20when%20(default())%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20color%3A%20red%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn%2F%2F%20custom%20(uncomment%20to%20enable)%3A%5Cn%2F*%5Cn.nav-item()%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20bar%20%7Bborder-width%3A%202px%7D%20%20%5Cn%7D%5Cn*%2F%5Cn%22%7D) (just one of zillion variants).